# sas output to pdf without overwriting it

Tags: sas

I want to output some plots to a existing pdf (4 pages). I need to add these plots in page 5 (all in the same page).

```
ods pdf file="\\path\Ex..pdf" startpage=no;

proc sgplot 

ods pdf close;
```

Ususally I create pdf using above code. But it will delete the previous content then create new things.

Comment: Is the existing PDF created somewhere via SAS or elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. It's created by another SAS program in the same processflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS cannot append to created PDF's currently. If the other PDF was created within SAS it may be possible to use proc document to re-organize output to create a single PDF file.

You can use Adobe Professional or another PDF application to append PDF's. If this needs to be automated a VB script can be created and run from within SAS, but Adobe Professional or the other PDF application will still be required and called externally.

EDIT: 
The simplest method is to change where your ODS CLOSE is located so the PDF is written at once.

The second is to wrap each table in ODS document statements to create a document object and then replay it at a later point, aggregating all tables in the same location.

Code from here:
http://support.sas.com/kb/35/375.html

```
/* Use a LIBNAME statement or directory appropriate for your SAS session */
libname docs "c:\temp";

/* Route the PROC REPORT table to a document item store named FIRST in the DOCS library */
ods document name=docs.first;
proc report nowd data=sashelp.class(obs=10);
   title "first";
run;

/* Close the document itemstore */
ods document close;

/* Create a new document item store in which to save the second PROC REPORT table.
   This ODS DOCUMENT NAME= / ODS DOCUMENT CLOSE logic can be included in
   the original SAS session or a separate SAS session. */
ods document name=docs.second;

proc report nowd data=sashelp.vtable(obs=20);
   title "Second";
   column libname memname nobs nvar crdate;
run;

ods document close;

ods document name=docs.third;

proc report nowd data=sashelp.class;
   title "Third";
run;

ods document close;

/* In the same SAS session or a new SAS session, combine the results 
   of the three document item stores with PROC DOCUMENT.  */
libname docs "c:\temp";
ods pdf file="combined_2.pdf";

proc document name=docs.first;
   replay;
run;
quit;

proc document name=docs.second;
   replay;
run;
quit;

proc document name=docs.third;
   replay;
run;
quit;

ods pdf close;
```